# Windows phone 8 slow text input in TextBox or PhoneTextBox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, textbox

I have some page with **TextBox** or **PhoneTextBox** (from toolkit): Part of xaml code.
I animate scrollviewer (opacity and XProperty), befor I set datacotext for textbox.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentScroller" 
                      Visibility="Collapsed"
                      Margin="35,0,35,0">
            <ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform />
            </ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>
            <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="CreationgDate"
                           Text="{Binding CreationDate, StringFormat='Created: {0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}'}" 
                           Style="{StaticResource CreationDateTextStyle}"
                           Grid.Row="0"/>
                <toolkit:PhoneTextBox x:Name="BodyData"
                                      InputScope="Chat"
                                      Text="{Binding Body, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"                              
                                      LostFocus="BodyData_LostFocus"
                                      TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                      AcceptsReturn="True"
                                      Grid.Row="1">                        
                </toolkit:PhoneTextBox>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

I update DataSource in event LostFocus:

```
    // this I set datacontex
    private async void Item_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PageHeader.DataContext = CreationgDate.DataContext = BodyData.DataContext = activeItem;            
        await AnimateChangePage();
    }

    private void BodyData_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BindingExpression be = NoteBodyData.GetBindingExpression(PhoneTextBox.TextProperty);
        be.UpdateSource();
    }
```

TROUBLE: When text in textbox has 400-500 chars and more, then text input in textbox very slow, and keyboard have a lag response.
I test app in real device (not emulator), other app with same functionality (from app store)  work fine without lag and slow input.

Help me with this thing please.
And sorry for my lang (not english) :) .

Comment: I haven't used such long textboxes, but as a test, what if you changed the binding from Explicit to LostFocus and got rid of the lostfocus event? msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: My first variant: `Text="{Binding Body, Mode=TwoWay}"` , with Default UpdateSourceTrigger, but result is same.

Comment: It is hard to tell. Often this sort of slowing down is caused by a lot of notifications going on in the background as objects are updated. Is your model inheriting from BindableBase, or are you using an MVVM framework?

Comment: I use simple class with property `public string Body{ get {...} set { if(_body != value) _body = value; } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following our comment discussion, this is the best answer I can give:

1. Run the app on your phone in debug mode.
2. Either straight away, or when the issue occurs, set a breakpoint in the set statement on the body property(above if property=value). When the breakpoint is hit, use the call stack to work out what is causing the update and the watch window to see the current value. You may find something is trying to update it repeatedly.
3. If there is anything else updating the body, there are subscribed events, or viewmodel events being fired that relate to the body, stick breakpoints on them and see if they are firing excessively.
4. Failing that, Stick breakpoints everywhere. For example, it may be losing focus for some reason, and triggering that event more than it should be. It could also be something else rending in the background.
5. All that fails, try not binding the textbox and going WinForms style of set the value and then get it back later. Remove all unnecessary events. You can then build it back up and identify the cause. If it is slow without a binding and attached events, then I really would be out of ideas.

Generally, i have found this sort of thing relates to events firing that I didn't expect. I see you are checking the incoming value is different, which will stop the dreaded MVVM property loop, but without seeing the rest of the application, its hard to narrow the issue down further.